# Ubuntu 14.04 email notification does not work

Tags: 14.04, email, imap

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and have a Gmail account and I would like get notifications about incoming emails.

I have installed Unity Mail. Unity Mail opens a Chrome tab when I click to its icon.

-> that means the setup should be correct.
But I do not receive any notification (the letter icon does not change, no popups,...). So I would like to ask you there, how do I fix this issue to get notifications when there is incoming email?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gmail as your primary email source and want a third part email client to have access you will need to allow Google to grant permission for third part app. It should be some were in your Gmail account and settings, you might want to do a search for more information on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks,
it seems that that client does not meet the google security conditions. I am getting email everytime it tried to log in.